# Change the value of a textbox from a Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I have this class :

```
public class ColorPan
{       
    public void ColorText(string txtText)
    {
        txtText = "Stackoverflow";
    }
}
```

I Use it in my main form :

```
ColorPan cp = new ColorPan();
cp.ColorText(txtbox.text);
```

I will like that the text of txtbox should change by the one in the class (Stackoverflow).

Comment: A `TextBox` is not a string - you need to pass the control in, not the value in the control.

Comment: Your method is accepting a string - it's very unclear what you're trying to achieve here, to be honest. If you want to change `txtbox.Text`, you should use `txtbox.Text = /* some expression returning a string*`

Comment: Are you using `Void` in your actual code?  Because that would not compile...

Comment: Instead of passing a `string`, have you tried passing the `TextBox`? (strings are immutable, and can't be changed as you're trying to do) `public void ColorText(TextBox textBox) { textBox.Text = "StackOverflow"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class ColorPan
{       
    public void ColorText(TextBox txtControl)
    {
       txtControl.Text = "Stackoverflow";
    }
}
```

Use reference to TextBox:

```
ColorPan cp = new ColorPan();
cp.ColorText(txtbox);
```

you can modify all properties of a `TextBox` referenced in a void method of a class

Comment: Use better casing (`txtControl`) and address the `Void` will not compile issue and I'll upvote

Comment: Or at least make sure it compiles (`void` not `Void`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yeah I had to add that to my comment too

Comment: Thanks Very Much for answering in seconds, I tried it and it worked!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I copied the DevFranz_Tech code, i change the V to v in answere

Comment: @DevFranz_Tech if this work for you, please mark as valid answere

Comment: I'll just that can't do it before 5 minutes says Stackoverflow

Comment: This line makes no sense: "you can modifly all properties of textbox in a class void." . There's no such thing as a "void class"

Comment: @henocsalinas in addition to what Camilo said, you should still edit to use proper casing for the language.  Method parameters should be `camelCased`

Comment: im sorry, i dont speack good english, i changing the text of answere

Comment: @henocsalinas maybe just remove that last part then because it does not make _any_ sense